# Sprite Kit Physics Simulation - bodies never come to rest

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

With Sprite Kit physics I have a simple setup with a ball bouncing inside a rectangular edge shape.

It all works fine, however the ball never comes to rest. The resting property is always NO and I can see that the ball animation keeps making a little bit of movement when it should be resting.

Sprite Kit is based on Box2D and here there is a doSleep option on the physics world, but I cannot find something similar with Sprite Kit.

What am I missing?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for...[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471381/sprite-kit-physicsbody-resting-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

You should use restitution. A property for setting the bounciness of the physics body in sprite kit. Actually, it is a property describing how much energy a body retains when it bounces off of another body. Dot operator can be used with the ball's sprite name to access the restitution property.

Comment: The physicsbody of the ball has a restitution set at 0.8 and it bounces fine like a real ball and almost finds complete rest. It is like the Sprite Kit physics simulator does not recognise that the ball should be set to rest completely.

Comment: I would suggest you play with some varying values for your physics world gravity as well as the restitution of the ball and see which combination of both could help achieve what you desire.