# SpriteKit - Detect if sprite still moving/stopped

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want to detect if my moving sprite (After applying an impulse) has stopped. 
Is there something like an event/function that handles this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check physics body *velocity* vector to see if the node is moving in any direction. With something like this you would be probably fine :

```
if((yournode.physicsBody.velocity.dx == 0.0f) && (yournode.physicsBody.velocity.dy == 0.0f)) {
   //do your stuff
}
```

Also there is a property on node's physics body called [resting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/resting) which indicates whether the object is at rest within the physics simulation. So you could probably do something like this:

```
if(yourNode.physicsBody.resting ) {
 //do your stuff
 }
```

You can read about certain behaviours and recommendations about *resting* property [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475871/3402095).

Hope this helps

Comment: Beat me by a cup of coffee :)

Comment: @sangony That is an excuse :) I had mine a lot earlier, so I was good to go and write an answers :)

Comment: Fantastic - this was a great find after testing velocity for hours ;)