# Callback when body stopped. (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm developing a game using SpriteKit.
My hero can jump on platforms and fall down.
I need some kind of callback when a hero stopped moving after successful/unsuccessful jump.
I know about "resting" property, but I'd like to use some event. Something like "didBodyStopped".
How to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to detect whether it stopped moving, or whether he's now back on the "ground" after a jump?

If the latter, you can implement this by properly setting the `contactTestBitMask` on the physics bodies of the player and the ground, and using the `contactDelegate`of the `physicsWorld` of your scene. You'll then get calls to `didBeginContact:` to let you know of the contact (you may have to do a few checks to be sure it's the kind of contact you're looking for).

If you really want the former, you can explore two options:

- add key-value observing on the `resting` property of your node. Not sure it is KVO-compliant, though.
- in `didSimulatePhysicsForScene:`, check the `resting` property of your node.

As pointed out by Whirlwind in the comments below, `resting` may not be the most reliable way to detect the node having stopped moving. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475871/3402095 for details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I'm searching a solution for the first option: to detect whether it stopped moving. I'll try to implement it via checking in didSimulatePhysicsForScene:, but seems like it's not the best way.

Comment: @jcaron Relying on "resting" property may not be the most accurate way to find out if body is moving/not moving. It may happen that "resting" property returns true even if it is not moving at all...In real world example, this means if player lands on platform and everything looks like he is not moving, if you print out the "resting" property you will see something like this - true,true,true,false, true, true, true, false...Read more here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25475871/3402095

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not use physics but could help you.

If your `Player` is jumping using `SKAction` you can use the callback of the `runAction` method.

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {

    func jump() {
        let delta : CGFloat = 50
        let up = SKAction.moveToY(delta, duration: 1)
        let down = SKAction.moveToY(-delta, duration: 1)
        let jump = SKAction.sequence([up, down])
        self.runAction(jump) {
            print("Jump has finished")
        }
    }
}
```